# What does it mean for a topos to be "generated" by some kind of objects?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

Is there a universal definition of what that phrase should mean?

Suppose we are considering objects of a topos with a particular property, call them $P$-objects (I have in mind the case where P="compact", as in Johnstone's Topos Theory). What does the phrase "the topos is generated by its $P$-objects" mean? It looks like it usually means that every object is a coproduct of two $P$-objects. But I think sometimes it means something like "every object is a filtered/cofiltered limit/colimit of $P$-objects".

Comment: See if http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/separator fits into the context. This is the usual meaning.

Comment: In topos theory anyway...